# How to display form fields inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

I want to make my form fields to be displayed in one line. Here's the HTML of my form:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <ul class="hypers">
      <li><input type="email" class="form-control emailfield" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="ENTER YOUR EMAIL"></li>
      <li><input type="email" class="form-control zipfield" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="ZIP CODE"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

As you can I added the `ul` element and placed each of the fields in a `li` tag and then I added this code to the css:

```
.hypers li{
  display: inline;
}
```

But the problem is it displays the form in this way and not in one line:

[image: print screen]

So how can I fix this issue ?!

Comment: maybe because of width??

Comment: It's definitely the with of the container, if the width is less than the sum of the  inputs withs then they are moved to the next line.

A workaround could be making the inputs' with proportional. Eg. 50% each, or less if you consider the margins.

Play with this to understand what I mean: https://fiddle.jshell.net/enk995f9/

Answer (score 1):

> 1) only `lis` in one line

```
.hypers li {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

```css
.hypers li {
    width:50%;
    float: left;
}

.btn {
    margin-left:40px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <ul class="hypers">
            <li><input type="email" class="form-control emailfield" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="ENTER YOUR EMAIL"></li>
            <li><input type="email" class="form-control zipfield" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="ZIP CODE"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

> 2) All in one line

```
.hypers li {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
}
```

```css
.hypers li {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <ul class="hypers">
            <li><input type="email" class="form-control emailfield" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="ENTER YOUR EMAIL"></li>
            <li><input type="email" class="form-control zipfield" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="ZIP CODE"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some CSS classes to your HTML:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group like-table">
    <ul class="hypers like-table-row">
      <li class="like-table-cell"><input type="email" class="form-control emailfield" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="ENTER YOUR EMAIL"></li>
      <li class="like-table-cell"><input type="email" class="form-control zipfield" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="ZIP CODE"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and use the following CSS:

```
.like-table { display: table }
.like-table-row { display: table-row }
.like-table-cell { display: table-cell }
```

Also you can check the same in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hemant_arora/qcg6mxwe/)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using the class `.d-inline-block` to the `li` elements like so

```
<li class="d-inline-block">
    <input type="email" class=" form-control emailfield" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="ENTER YOUR EMAIL">
</li>
```

Bootstrap will take care of the rest of the alignment.

Here is the full code [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y9peo3tv/)